# In PHP, is there a way to intercept a compile time fatal error, if OPCache is disabled?

Tags: php, error-handling, compiler-errors

**The setting**

PHP 7.3 . I have an autoloader that loads classes and interfaces during code execution. Also I have a global error handler which processes all types of errors ( `error_reporting(E_ALL)` ). Processing all errors means, it creates an `ErrorException` and throws it. The code is contained in a try-catch. And the catch code logs all objects of type `\Throwable`. All of the mentioned works fine, except ...

**The problem**

If a class implements an interface but I forget to implement a method or got a typo in a method name, PHP does not pass an error to the global error handler. It only creates a message and writes it directly to the output. The message reads like this:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class classABC contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or 
implement the remaining methods ( interfaceXYZ::method123 ) in <b>example.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
```

**Additinal Information**

In my web research I read about PHP run time vs compile time and that these are indistinguishable, if OPcache is disabled. Debugging shows, the message is written to the output during run time, meaning when code execution gets to the code where the class is referenced and the autoloader loads class and then interface code. In my web research I read about OPcode and OPcache. And as far as I understand, I believe this means, that OPcaching is disabled on the server. Also no module named `Zend OPcache` is shown by `phpinfo()` . Just in case this is important for a solution.
Also, using the debugger shows, that this error is never passed on to the global error handler.

**My own guess**

After the interface code is loaded during run time, PHP is in compile mode and checks if the class implements all methods, declared by the interface. But because it is in compile mode, the fatal error is not passed to the error handler.

**Question**

Is there any way, by which I can intercept this error and pass it on to the global error handler, so I can catch and log it?

Comment: This is a compile-time error, it [can't be caught](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) with `set_error_handler()` and it should never make it into production. It's not really any different than a syntax error like a missing a closing brace. A simple static analysis tool like PHPStan, running in a pre-commit hook or a server-side pipeline, will find these issues before you deploy. Heck, even your basic IDE will highlight such code in red.

Comment: You can not catch them, but you can report them using the `register_shutdown_function` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-e-error-error).  But that will probably not cover your requirement.  Like @AlexHowansky mentioned this is a compile error. While php tries to load the classes it fails (hence the Fatal).